# Automatic flag in a checkbox after datediff

Tags: php, datediff

I need some help on the following issue.
what i have:
Date1 (column1)
Date2 (column2).
What i need is a simple datediff between those 2 values.
if Date2 - Date1 => 10 days then i need an automatic flag in column3.

Please any suggestion?

Comment: What have you come up with so far? Show us your code and we'll be happy to help you to make it work.

Comment: well..nothing more of this:

$var1 = $values['Date Activation'];
$var2 = $values['Date Build-up'];
$var3 = $values['Post Provisioning'];
$flag = ($var1-$var2);
If $flag >10 
???

Comment: And what is not working with the given code?

Comment: the issue is that i'm not able to give a code for automatic flag of column 3 when the values are more than 10...i really don't know how to do :-(

Answer (score 0):

Simply run this query:

```
UPDATE myTable SET column3 = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(column2,column1) >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```